# Overlay a div to the dimensions of an image

Tags: html, css, image, grid, overlay

This is a slightly fiddly question- essentially, I am making a grid of images where a coloured overlay (div) is displayed upon rollover, with a bit of text within that div. This is very similar to this website- http://twoarmsinc.com/work/category/all. To do this with a div instead instead of an image would be easy- you would nest the overlay inside the other div and set width and height to 100%. However, since you can't nest within an image, and the image is responsively changing size, how should I go about this? I'm not sure background-image will work because I am using a responsive grid system (Simple Grid).

Here's a CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iIsGm/

html:

```
<div>
   <div class='overlay'></div>
   <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="thumb">
</div>
```

css:

```
.overlay{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#333;
position:relative;
z-index:10;
}
```

Apologies for the ambiguity- any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will first need to swap `.overlay` with the `img`, so it comes second in the stack.

You have some options for the `.container` div, but you'll need to set a width to set up a grid. I didn't include it in the fiddle, but you will likely want to set `img` to `max-width: 100%; width: auto; height: auto;`, so they can resize and keep their aspect ratios when the browser is resized. For `.container`, you can also use `float: left` with a set `width`. I used `display: inline-block` here to reduce the amount of code.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/69gHw/)**

**[DEMO with multiple divs floating and simple grid](http://jsfiddle.net/69gHw/2/)**

CSS:

```
.overlay{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

img {
  display: block;  
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.container:hover > .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="thumb">
    <div class='overlay'>Some text</div>
</div>
```